# If we know the convex conjugate of $f(x,y)$, what can we say about the conjugate of $f$ in $x$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Say $f^*(x,y)$ is the convex conjugate of $f(x,y)$. Now take $g_{y_0}(x) := f(x, y_0)$. Is there any relationship between $g^*_{y_0}(x)$ and $f^*(x, y_0)$?

Comment: Honey have you looked at this: https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/68.pdf

Comment: @SarahPalinsAnger Thanks for the reference. But that doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Yes. $f^*(x,y_0)\ge g_{y_0}^*(x)$. Just write out the definitions and choose one variable in the sup for $f^*(x,y_0)$ to be $y_0$.

Answer (score 0):

They are of course the same. Writing $g_{y_0}(x)$ instead of $f(x,y_0)$ is only a typographical device to make it more evident that you consider $f$ as a function of $x$ alone for the moment.